# Set field in POJO after it was fetched through Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I'm currently using MongoDB to store the information of an account and Morphia to map the POJO to a document and vice versa.

One piece of information that I store is the IP that the account used for the last login, but this information could change every time they login, so I don't want to load this information from the document that's fetched from MongoDB. I know that I can have a setter in the POJO to set this field after the field was instantiated with the value stored in the document, but I rather keep it immutable once it's instantiated, so is there a way to make Morphia use a given value for it instead of the value stored in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not in such a dynamic fashion, no.  Your best bet is to load that entity via some service class then set the IP address before returning it back out to the application.